# Quadratic graph assist Python on Calculator

Tags: python, math, micropython

Hi all I am attempting to code a quadratic graph assistance tool for my maths class in school.

I've coded a few other maths tools over the years and all have worked reasonably well however when I tried to load this new code to the calculated and run it it states that there was a syntax error. I believe that the calculator(fx-CG50 AU) runs on micropython which to my understanding is similar but a bit more case sensitive so Ive tried my best to make it work for a few hours by changing cases putting spaces between operators etc. but to no success. Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated :). The code is below:

```py
print('Ax ^ 2 + Bx + C')

astr = input('A: ')

bstr = input('B: ')

cstr = input('C: ')

a = float(astr)

b = float(bstr)

c = float(cstr)

delta = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)

print('discriminant:', delta)

if delta == 0:
    
    x1 = float((((-1 * b) - (delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a))))
    
    x1int = int(x1)
    
    
    if x1 == x1int:
        
        print('x intercept: (', x1, ', 0)')
    

    else:
        
        sb = float(-1 * b)

        sa = float(2 * a)
        
        print('x intercept: ( (', sb, ' + sqr(', delta,'))/', sa,'), 0)')

    if a > 0:
        print('Nature of Graph is: Cuts the x-axis twice. Concave up.')

    elif a < 0:
        print('Nature of Graph is: Cuts the x-axis twice. Concave down.')

    else:
        print('this aint no quadratic tho')




elif delta > 0:

    x1 = float((((-1 * b) - (delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a))))

    x2 = float((((-1 * b) + (delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a))))
    
    x1int = int(x1)

    if x1 == x1int:

        print('x intercepts: (', x1, ', 0)', ' and (', x2, ', 0)' )
    

    else:
        
        sb = -1 * b

        sa = 2 * a
        
        print('x intercepts: ( (', sb, ' + sqr(', delta,'))/', sa, '), 0) and ( (', sb, ' - sqr(', delta,'))/', sa, '), 0)') 

    if a > 0:
        print('Nature of Graph is: Cuts the x-axis once. Concave up.')

    elif a < 0:
        print('Nature of Graph is: Cuts the x-axis once. Concave down.')

    else:
        print('this aint no quadratic tho')



elif delta < 0:

    print('No x intercepts')
    
    if a > 0:
        print('Nature of Graph is: Lies entirely above the x-axis. Concave up. Positive definite.')

    elif a < 0:
        print('Nature of Graph is: Lies entirely below the x-axis. Concave down. Negative definite.')

    else:
        print('this aint no quadratic tho')

else:
    
    print('error....!.')

print('y intercept: (0, ', c, ')')

xvcord = float((-1 * b) / (2 * a))

yvcord = float((a * ((xvcord) ** 2)) + (b * (xvcord)) + c)

xvcordint = int(xvcord)

yvcordint = int(yvcord)

if xvcordint == xvcord:
    
    if yvcordint == yvcord:
        
        print('vertex: (', xvcord, ', ', yvcord, ')')

    else:
        
        top = -1 * ( b ** 2) + ( 4 * a * c)
        bot = 4 * a


        print('vertex: (', xvcord, ', ',top, '/', bot, ')') 

else:
    
    if yvcordint == yvcord:
        
        top = -1 * b
        bot = 2 * a
        print('vertex: (', top, '/', bot, ', ', yvcord, ')')

    else:
        
        topx = -1 * b
        botx = 2 * a
        
        topy = -1 * (b ** 2) + (4 * a * c)
        boty = 4 * a


        print('vertex: (', topx, '/', botx, ', ',topy, '/', boty, ')')
```

The error output on the calculator was SyntaxError: invalid syntax. The calculator doesn't say where this error occurred etc.

It was originally in a while loop and with anotations but I took those out to try and strip it down to the basics so I could narrow down what is messing with it :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code runs fine on desktop Python.  The "space" issue in MicroPython is that Python allows an identifier immediately after a number and uPython doesn't.  For example `x=1or 2` is valid Python.  People almost never write that anyway.

Comment: To get a full traceback, you could run the code in the REPL while connected to the device over USB (I'm assuming that's how you upload the code?).  If not USB, then maybe a serial connection?  Without a traceback, only a MicroPython expert has a chance at helping you.